# Do giant-kin have a specific place in the Ordning?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

In 5th Edition, the word Ordning refers to the hierarchy of the various breeds of giant. Among the so-called 'true' giants this order goes, from highest to lowest: Storm giants, Cloud giants, Fire, Frost, Stone, then Hill giants. Beneath Hill giants are various 'lesser' members of the giant family, including Two-headed Ettins, Deformed Formorians, Ogres and Trolls.

Do the giant-kin have a place within this pecking order?

Answer (score 6):

5th edition doesn't give much information about Giants and their Ordning. As far as I know, here are the two relevant text blocks in the Monster Manual :

> **The Ordning**
>
> ---
>
> At the highest level of the ordning, the races of the giants are also ranked according to status. Storm giants are the highest in the ordning, followed by cloud giants, fire giants, frost giants, stone giants, hill giants, and finally giant kin such as fomorians, ettins, and ogres. (MM, p. 149 - *Giants*)

and :

> In the giants'complex social structure (known as the ordning), ogres
>   rank beneath the lowest giants in status. (MM, p. 238 - *Ogres*)

These two blocks seem to answer your question. The order in the ordning, from the highest to the lowest rank, is :

1. All the true giants
2. The giant-kin (including formorians and ettins)
3. The ogres

Trolls aren't mentioned at all.

It is worth noting that in D&D 2nd edition, ettins were considered **true giants**, sitting just before the giant-kin in the Ordning (sources [here](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Ordning_%28social_structure%29) and [here](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Giant)) and that giant-kin included the following creatures ([source](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Giant-kin)) : firbolgs, formorians, verbeegs, voadkyn, cyclopes, cyclopskins, and ogres.